# My former PhD supervisor has published conclusions from my thesis without citing my thesis. Is this ok?

Tags: publications, thesis, advisor

My former PhD supervisor has just published a paper on a scientific subject investigated by me in my thesis.  The subject (or question posed), was an idea that I came up solely during my PhD and which I chose to investigate as a sub topic - my conclusions were published in my thesis in 2015 and I assume (from a legal statement in the thesis), that I own the copyright.

The paper just published has taken my hypothesis and explored it in more depth.  Some of my studies have been repeated by other people in the lab.  Moreover, some of the key conclusions made by me in my thesis have been made again.  I have not been credited in any way.

Is this plagiarism and should I pursue this?  I’ve left academia so no longer publish anyway.

Comment: I'm going to close this out. This is an interesting question, but as noted in the discussion below, there are not enough details for us to make a useful answer (too bad that we did not request these details at the time). In particular, we can't really tell whether they merely redid your analysis (which is a question of novelty) or whether they used your work without citing you (which is a question of plagiarism). Then in the latter case, the cost-benefit analysis of pursuing a plagiarism charge is a whole separate thing.

Answer (score -4):

> My former PhD supervisor has just published a paper on a scientific subject investigated by me in my thesis...The paper [takes] my hypothesis and explored it in more depth. Some of my studies have been repeated by other people in the lab. Moreover, some of the key conclusions made by me in my thesis have been made again. I have not been credited in any way.
>
> Is this plagiarism and should I pursue this?

This is not plagiarism: As you have noted, *the paper [takes your] hypothesis and explore[s] it in **more depth*** (emphasis added), i.e., the paper goes beyond your results to provide something new. To determine whether plagiarism appears elsewhere probably requires more information than the OP has provided.

> I have not been credited in any way.

A citation to your thesis or any of your other published works would be appropriate, perhaps even required, e.g., if the paper is entirely built upon your work.

Comment: -1. The issue of plagiarism is completely orthogonal to the issue of novelty.

Comment: Not only appropriate but required.

Comment: @sgf You seem to argue that a *new* study can plagiarise an *old* study. That's just not possible. Nonetheless, I'll clarify that plagiarism is somewhat different, I didn't think that point needed making.

Comment: @user2768 Taking the first non-wikipedia definition that Google gives me, the [University of Oxford](https://www.ox.ac.uk/students/academic/guidance/skills/plagiarism?wssl=1) defines plagarism as "presenting someone else’s work or ideas as your own, with or without their consent, by incorporating it into your work without full acknowledgement." This is about _work or ideas_, not only about the totality of results.

Comment: @sgf Without far more detail, we cannot determine whether plagiarism has been committed. We can suggest how it might not have been.

Comment: @henning Not necessarily...

Comment: @user2768 "This is not plagiarism." That's just too strong a statement if we're not sure. But copying the study design without crediting the designer seems enough to me to determine that plagiarism has, in fact, been committed.

Comment: @sgf "explor[ing] in *more depth*" is clearly not plagiarism. Whether plagiarism appears elsewhere is an entirely different question. Of course, I can only base my answer on the information provided, and more information is needed to provide a definitive answer.